# Strategies, approaches, methods for motivating innovation adoption in academia

Tags: research-process, collaboration, science, colleagues

I'm curious about what strategies, approaches and/or methods people (successfully) use in academia for motivating colleagues to adopt innovative research collaboration mechanisms, workflows and/or tools. Please share your experience or point to proven range of approaches.

The following is in lieu of background information. Currently I'm leading a university project for developing a software platform for scientific research and e-collaboration in a particular scientific domain. Earlier I have installed, configured and publicized another software platform with a goal of increasing research productivity and make scientific collaboration and reproducibility easier within our group and beyond. Unfortunately, after initial decent interest of some people, most of them (and the rest) went back to "doing business as usual". I understand that researchers are busy and are under a lot of pressure to meet/exceed expectations and due to career advancement demands. I don't want to shove innovation down people's throats, but, at the same time, I'm quite frustrated that people do not see (or don't want to see, or don't care) significant potential benefits of some new ways in doing research and/or scientific software development in academia.

Considering the high visibility of my current project, I started thinking about / trying to come up with novel strategies and approaches to **motivating** colleagues in academia toward adopting *innovative methods/tools* (i.e., Agile) through *emphasizing* their **potential benefits** and/or **lost opportunity** in research productivity and other aspects, when such innovative methods/tools are not used.

Comment: Why do you believe that "another software platform" improves productivity? And why your "new ways in doing research" are better than any other method that other people use? I do not doubt neither your motivation, skills or your good will, but why do you believe that you know better than your colleagues?

Comment: @Alexandros: I'll start with your 2nd question and then will return to the 1st one. I think that "new ways in doing research" are better than some (I haven't said "any") other methods that other people use, because IMHO they potentially improve productivity, along with offering other benefits (i.e., reproducibility). They potentially improve productivity etc., based on logic and my prior experience, It's not that I understand better, it's just 1) I have research background as well, plus 2) I have significant (relative to other people in my group) software development and process exposure.

Comment: @Alexandros: (cont'd) That (my last sentence) is not to say that other people in my group don't have software development and process exposure (some of them might very well be better developers than I'm), but they significantly more focus on research per se in their subject domain. In other words, I tend to see the bigger picture (have a wider focus) - again, it's all relative and I'm not trying to generalize anything.

Comment: You have to be very very very careful. Statements like "I tend to see the bigger picture" and "I'm quite frustrated that people do not see (or don't want to see, or don't care) significant potential benefits" are guaranteed to backfire.

Comment: If you haven't already heard of it, you may be interested in a topic called [Change Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_management).   When you get down to it, you are trying to practice [psychological persuasion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persuasion) - and academics are rather well known for being...resistant to being told what to do, generally. These topics have spawned entire fields of research, and dozens of job titles, and I feel that ultimately this is simply too broad to be answerable in the Stack Exchange Q&A format.

Comment: Learning new tools takes a lot of time and effort that could also be used for research. This can be a bad trade-off, especially for junior academics. The promised future benefits may simply fail to materialize, if they're unable to secure a permanent position due to reduced research productivity meanwhile.

Comment: I think you've made it too much about the process.  Try making it about the people.  Seek out the like-minded instead of expecting them to flock to you.  Students included.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's excellent and direct feedback, even the some that makes wrong assumptions about me or what I'm trying to do. Below I will comment individually.

Comment: @MaartenBuis: Thank you for the warning. I have considered the backfiring aspect before posting those statements and made a conscious decision to prefer an open/honest and direct tone to fuzzy statements. My hope is that people will understand that I'm trying to present myself in any way superior to my colleagues, but what I'm thinking and saying might be true simply because of the following: 1) my potentially more diverse IT experience (again, no offense or generalizations are implied); (to be continued)

Comment: @MaartenBuis: (cont'd) 2) most of my respected colleagues are much more (and more deeply) involved in specific research areas of one or more scientific domains, so they (or most of them) simply don't have _time_ (and, for some, desire) to see their research through a **larger variety** of _perspectives_, including the "big picture" 30,000 feet view. I'm not saying that I always see the bigger picture, but I think that often I do. Plus, my statements do not imply the _context_ of subject domain knowledge, but rather the one of research workflows and collaboration strategies, methods and tools.

Comment: @BrianDHall: Thank you for your valuable comment. I certainly was aware of change management (CM) field, but haven't had major practical experience, spearheading and implementing significant changes, especially in academia environment. I will definitely consider refreshing my knowledge on CM as well as using relevant strategies and approaches in my attempts in helping my colleagues (and my university) to use innovation in research workflows and collaboration in order to be more productive and, thus, more competitive.

Comment: @JouniSirén: Thank you. I agree - your point aligns with my current sentiment in regard to being one of the major reasons for weak adoption of new methodologies and/or tools in academia. I guess, one of the approaches in fighting this problem is to create a circle of early adopters, who not only will enjoy the promised benefits (willing to take some risks first), but also will become change ambassadors in a particular environment. In order to help those early adopters to minimize said risks, I think it makes sense to use an adaptation of _Agile_ methodology (short and small change iterations).

Comment: @DaveKaye: Thank you for the comment. I'm always trying to use my people and communication skills to (genuinely) establish rapport and build collaboration on this, as a _foundation_, rather than on the process. However, any work (even creative, such as art or science) implies a _process_ (with different entropy levels), so when people are nice, but don't want to change their research routines, you can't expect any significant improvements in their productivity, research reproducibility and/or other benefits. Finding like-minded people is one of approaches I'm using, but it might not be enough.

Comment: Could we see some screenshots of the software?  I'd bet $20 the main reason people do not want to use it is that the UI is bad.  Good UI is much more important (and much, _much_ more difficult) than most developers realize.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: No, you cannot, as the software (as planned) doesn't exist yet (so, you just saved $20 :-). It's a good point, though, and I'm certainly paying attention to the UX/UI aspect. However, it seems that you (and some other people) have missed my main point: my concerns and efforts in regard to _future adoption_ are due to my desire to **plan** and **embed** relevant strategies and approaches into ongoing development process

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I'd bet $50 that, in fact, the main reason people don't want to use it is that they don't feel that it solves any actual problem that they have.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: How do you know that people _"don't want"_ to use some tools or approaches? Have you considered that some people are _too busy_ to change their research routine that is comfortable to them (but not necessarily optimal in terms of productivity and other aspects)? Have you considered that some other people are _not ready_ to perform a mental shift toward different approaches? Having said that, you, as many others, also missed the _focus_ of my question: it's not about that adoption of a "small" tool in the past, but rather about potential adoption of the "big" tool in the future.

Comment: To those, who have placed my question on hold. Existing answers, while not perfect, are quite good in partial answering of my question and I'm satisfied with them (plus, there might be others coming). This is just another confirmation that this question is totally answerable with regard to both scope and size. Therefore, I am hoping that your decision will be reconsidered, so that other people will have a chance to provide their answers in academia's spirit of open discussion and encouraging different perspectives.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh "How do you know that people 'don't want' to use some tools or approaches?" You said as much yourself! People start to use it but then stop.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: The emphasis of my previous comment is on _want_ **versus** other potential reasons (being too busy, effort for a mental shift, distractions, etc.). I didn't say they stopped, because the didn't _want_ to use.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh I'm sorry but you're kidding yourself. If these people wanted to use your stuff, they'd continue to use it. The fact that they used it for a while and then stopped using it says very strongly that it had no significant net advantage (i.e., no significant advantage, period, or disadvantages that outweighed any significant advantage). Or do you really believe that these people have so little control over their lives and their research methodologies that they can't do things they want to do, even when those things are beneficial to their careers? That just doesn't add up.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I respectfully disagree. And can clarify why (I haven't included these details initially to make my question compact). When I said that my colleagues used the first (infrastructural) system, I didn't specify for how long. In reality what happened is that some people from my group "used" the system just to extent of registering in it. So, effectively, nobody, but me, really used the system. So, your argument is invalid, because it is based on the wrong assumption / interpretation. (to be continued)

Comment: @DavidRicherby: (cont'd) Moreover, as I mentioned, the system is infrastructural and, thus, is not a core element of people's research. Thus, even if it would be used for a while and then abandoned, it would be understandable due to being non-essential for the research. So, I used that example just to provide some context. The other, large system (under development) is a different story. It is essential to research (though the option of doing "business as usual" still remains). (to be continued)

Comment: @DavidRicherby: (cont'd) That is why I am seeking various solutions in order to plan accordingly, embed those solutions into the overall strategy and, thus, maximize chances for the system's adoption and success.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh " I said that my colleagues used the first (infrastructural) system [...] [but] effectively, nobody, but me, really used the system." Well, no wonder my arguments are invalid. They're based on the assumption that, when you say something, that thing isn't a total misrepresentation of reality. Like I said, you're deluding yourself.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Well, I had no intention of misrepresenting reality. I'm sorry, if you and some other people feel that way. Perhaps, mentioning the 1st (infrastructural) system was not the best idea - I just wanted to **set the context**. However, the core of my question is about the _future system_ and I think I made that clear enough. I'm not sure why people focused on something that is not the core of the question...

Comment: @DavidRicherby: One more point. I just re-read my question and I don't see words that suggest specific interpretation of people's time length of use of the 1st system. My phrase "after initial decent interest of some people" does not imply significant time frame, quite the opposite: "initial" implies a short period of time. Having said that, I could have done a better job in making sure the question is clear to degree that doesn't allow for invalid assumptions.

Comment: OK. In that case, it sounds like this whole comment thread is the result of people getting confused. Apologies for my share of the mess.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Thank you. No problem at all - we all have introduced our respective shares of confusion. But it was me who has started it all :-).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify, so that others who share the misunderstanding don't have to read through an extended comment thread. Then you can delete and flag comments that have been made obsolete as a result. (Editing the question will also push it into the review queue for potential reopening.)

Comment: @ff524: Thank you for the suggestion. Will do that as soon as I can.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh there has been quite a lot written on what you're trying to do as regards the field broadly known as "Knowledge Management."  A significant chunk of the research in to the field has been based on simply getting others to buy in to KM as an idea in the first place.  Try there?  For instance: http://www.tlainc.com/articl174.htm

Comment: @DaveKaye: I'm familiar with KM theory and (some) practice. However, standard approaches to implementing KM are too "heavy", as they focused on large organizations, non-academic environments and longer time frames. Since I'm trying to implement KM in _academia_, within _smaller scope_ and _shorter time frames_, I'm considering applying some **Agile** approaches, so it can be referred to as "Agile Academic KM" (C). So, I think it's more about _motivation_ and larger field / perspective of _change management_, as BrianDHall has mentioned. Nevertheless, I appreciate your comment and reference.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh I think you get this but I'm not suggesting you try KM, but rather that you look in to the countless examples KM literature has about trying to create buy-in for KM.  Just to clear that up.  ;-)

Comment: @DaveKaye: Oh, I see. Now it's much clearer to me what you've meant :-). Will certainly follow your advice. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm quite frustrated that people do not see (or don't want to see, or don't care) significant potential benefits of some new ways in doing research and/or scientific software development in academia.

Have you considered that those benefits may simply not be there, at least not to the extent that you hoped for them? One PhD student building a scientific prototype for a conference is not the same as building a product, and many ideas, concepts, and processes that are great for building a collaborative product on Facebook scale may simply be dead weight or even counter-productive for a PhD student in his daily development work. Frankly speaking, if people actually tried your new way of doing things but then went back to "the old way", this is at least some serious indication that there may actually be merit  to the old way beyond pure inertia. People typically don't revert to an inferior way of working on purpose after trying something new and better. Have you actually talked to people why they went back?

Anyway, if you wanted to sell your agile ideas to me, the core question to answer would be:

**What are concrete, plausible scenarios how your ideas would help *me* personally?**

Stay away from lofty but abstract concepts such as code quality, reproducibility, code reuse, etc. Explain how each researcher individually can profit. What sort of embarrassing bugs and mistakes can be prevented? In what sense can each researcher individually save time? What new papers can be written that we could not easily write the old way?

This requires you to understand extremely well how your colleagues are currently working and what their current pain points are. If whatever way they currently build software is efficient and reasonably bug-free for them, I highly question you will be able to convince them to do e.g., TDD "because that's what industry does". If they are usually able to reproduce their experiments well enough, you won't be able to convince them to set up Docker containers for everything in the future, just because Docker is the current hot shit.

If you actually have access to them, explain cases of *"lost opportunity in research productivity and other aspects, when such innovative methods/tools are not used"*. The important part here is that those cases are (a) real, or at least plausible based on the experience of your colleagues, and (b) damaging to me personally. For instance, it will be hard to convince PhD students to invest time setting up a code based / infrastructure purely for the sake o the next generation of students.

*(and, of course, stay far away from ever implying that my scepticism for your ideas is because you see the bigger picture and I don't)*

Comment: Excellent answer (+1). Thank you for your advice - you mention important points, most of which I'm aware of, though, and already trying to implement. Most people didn't quite get my question's emphasis on distinction between the not very good adoption for the smaller (infrastructural) project and my efforts to learn lessons from that and embed them into my plans (strategy, approaches) for the much larger (and much more scientific) ongoing development project. I have no intention to ever imply that someone cannot see the bigger picture - my point is that many people are just too busy to do so.

Answer (score 15):

The best way to illustrate the value of new tools is to effectively use them yourself. If you are an active researcher and you are twice as efficient as your peers, then your peers might ask you how you manage such a torrid pace.

It sounds like you are not an actual user of your own tools. Moreover, it sounds like researchers demonstrated a willingness to try your tools and were not impressed. I would advise concentrating your energies on figuring out why these researchers chose to go back to "business as usual". You are most likely to succeed if you start from the premise that they know how to do their jobs effectively.

Comment: Very good point (+1). Unfortunately, you've got the wrong impression, as using approaches and tools I'm advocating for, is exactly what I have been doing, am doing and plan on continuing to do so (to a certain degree). However, I'm seeking supplemental strategies, approaches, methods and tools to help me with my efforts. "... and were not impressed" - no, they were and are too busy (plus other reasons) to change their research routines to adopt new approaches and tools. Plus, some tools are not ready yet - they are in development, so I can't blame people for not using what's not available yet.

Answer (score 7):

I'm a former consultant, and having people like what you provide is key to a consultant's life (doesn't mean I'm right, and it's quite a long while ago for me). It sounds as if you're looking at the wrong end of the chain of steps of how a new product is ideally rolled out - reception, and feedback by users of the finished product. On top of what other answers have stated, you appear to have skipped the 0th stage.

When you are tasked to implement a new tool, you are likely given broad ideas of what the tool is to achieve. But you'll always run up against people being used to old tools, and both liking them and loathing them for some of their aspects. To ensure buy-in, or at least make it more likely, you should push for an interview stage before you start with any work on the tool. Get a solid understanding of the current situation by spending time with the old tool, then prepare a questionnaire for (some of) its users. Tell them that you have been tasked to create a new tool, and strive to make it as useful for them as possible. For this, ask, among others, about

1. What is essential to you in any such tool?
2. What would you like to see again which you currently have, with as little change as possible?
3. Which aspects of the current tool do you loath?
4. Which additional features would you welcome?
5. (assuming you are already considering options, solicit feedback on them)
6. Is there any cross-integration with other tools this tool should have?

There are obviously many more question to ask, but a lot depend on the project at hand.

I would then also ask for one of the later users as a during-project contact with who you share progress to get some in-development feedback. And after roll-out, a training session, and going from desk to desk to help people get set up, will help.

While you can never guarantee that a tool will be willingly adopted, adoption will be much less likely if its users do not feel that they have been involved in its development.

Comment: Excellent answer and good points (+1). I'm already interviewing people (as part of _requirements elicitation_ process), so, at least that, I hope I'm doing right :-). My concerns and efforts in regard to _future adoption_ are due to my desire to **plan** and **embed** relevant strategies and approaches into ongoing _development process_ (and interviews are part of it). Interestingly, a set of my interview questions includes most of those you've mentioned. However, I hope to be able to improve it, though.